# change basic accourdion panel color arrow angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

i have accourdion panel and i want to change arrow color in accourdion . 
[image]

i write this in this css but it not work :

```
.mat-expansion-panel {
  .mat-expansion-indicator {
    .mat-expansion-indicator::after{
      color:red !important;
      border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    }
  }
}
```

**How can i change color of arrow ????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ::ng-deep along with material class to override default style.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-expansion-indicator::after {
      color:red !important;
      border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ze5z6t)